# Rivepod - create StateNotifier with parameter in input

Tags: flutter, riverpod

from te first page of [Rivepod](https://riverpod.dev/it/) library I found this example.

```
final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Counter, int>((ref) {
  return Counter();
});

class Counter extends StateNotifier<int> {
  Counter() : super(0);
  void increment() => state++;
}
```

Now, what I want to ask is: what is the right way to do something like this below?

```
class Counter extends StateNotifier<int> {
  Counter({int? value}) : super(value ?? 0);
  void increment() => state++;
}
```

I want that my `counterProvider` can have optional parameters in input, my use case is a StateNotifier used to manage a edit/create page.

Comment: `.family` may help

Comment: Got ans? Having same problem, . family showing error with statenotifieprovider

Comment: @Livin What kind of error? `.family` solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```dart
final valueProvider = StateProvider<Counter, int>((ref) => return 5);

final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Counter, int>((ref) {
  final value = ref.watch(valueProvider);

  return Counter(value);
});

class Counter extends StateNotifier<int> {
  Counter(int value) : super(value ?? 0);
  void increment() => state++;
}
```

Also, you can try using the modifier [.family](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family/)

That change state provider you can try like this:

```dart
ref.read(valueProvider.notifier).update((state) => 212);
// or use
...
ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        valueProvider.overrideWithValue(21332432),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
...
```

You can see about it [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/flutter_riverpod/ProviderScope-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

to have an optional parameter, this is how to do it:

```html
class Counter extends StateNotifier<int> {
  Counter({int value = 0}) : super(value);
  void increment() => state++;
}
```